# Array of objects and instance of a class

Tags: php, object

What would be the best practice to do this :

```
    class AwesomeClass {

            // Code

            public function test()
            {
                    foreach($objects->values as $v)
                    {
                            New SuperClass($v);
                    }

                    return $objects;
            }

    }

    class SuperClass {
            public function __construct($arg2)
            {
                    return trim($arg2);        
            }
    }

    $rule_the_world = New AwesomeClass($arg1);

    $king = $rule_the_world->test();
```

The previous code is obviously not working, I think I'm missing some major point of PHP OO.

Comment: Also, you probably want `new`, not `New`.

Comment: `Array of objects and instance of a class` dose not match what your persudo code... are you looking for some kind of Registry Design Pattern?

Comment: The point is I don't know how to tell this... I just want to apply class instance to each keys of an object. So after when you use this object in a foreach each is an instance of the class and you can use methods of this class on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very difficult to decipher what you're asking for, and the code you have is not recoverable.

---

## Code Errors

There are several errors in your code that are illogical:

- `AwesomeClass` has no constructor.

  - This makes passing `arg1` to `new AwesomeClass` meaningless
  - `arg1` is never initialized
- In `AwesomeClass::test()`, `objects` is never initialized and has no member `value`.

  - You will get a warning since it's not traversable
- `New SuperClass` (should be `new`, per standards) does nothing.
- `__construct()` cannot return a value.

---

## What You May Want

What I think you're going for is something like this:

```
class AwesomeClass implements IteratorAggregate {
   private $arg1;

   public function __construct(array $arg1) {
      $this->arg1 = $arg1;
   }

   public function getIterator() {
      return new ArrayIterator($this->arg1);
   }
}

class SuperClass {
   private $arg2;

   public function __construct($arg2) {
      $this->arg2 = $arg2;
   }

   public function __toString() {
      return "$this->arg2\n";
   }
}

$rule_the_world = new AwesomeClass(array('one', 'two', 'three'));
foreach ($rule_the_world as $sc) {
   $sc = new SuperClass($sc);
   echo $sc;
}
```

Note that it is redundant to create an `ArrayIterator` instance when `arg1` must already be an array, this is just an example.

Comment: Sorry, I understand my explanation is difficult to decipher... It's not what I want to do, I don't want to call the class inside my foreach, I want the class to create this object by itself.

So in the foreach I could do echo $sc->some_function()

Where some function is a function of SuperClass.